# Pages won't open after unexpected shut down

Tags: pages

I have OS X Yosemite v. 10.10.5.  After an update about 6 weeks ago Pages started refusing to respond, then shutting down unexpectedly.  Today Pages will not open at all.  I get the error message that Pages has shut down, do I want to reopen or report but reopen doesn't work.  Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

I'd try clearing the saved state files.

From Finder:

- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>     <kbd>G</kbd>
- Copy/paste `~/Library/Saved Application State`

Find the folder com.apple.iWork.Pages.savedState and delete the ***contents*** not the folder itself, as it's an alias.
That should give Pages a fresh start.

Comment: Still no luck, when you open pages it opens a series of documents (about 10) then crashes.

Comment: Clearing the saved state should prevent that - what's in the saved state, amongst other things, is the current open file list. I've tested & it works here. Sure you got everything when you cleared it?